# Error when installing pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl into python 3.5 32bit

Tags: python, pygame

When I try and load the above wheel into python 3.5 I get the following:

```
d:\Python35-32\Scripts> pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File 'd:\Python35-32\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__py", line 5, in ,module>
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

I have tried various methods to installing the wheel, however they all error out with the same message. I've checked the directories under Python35-32 and in the Scripts directory is:

```
easy_install
easy_install-3.5
pip
pip 3.5
pip3
and now pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl
```

Comment: Try `py -3.5 -m pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to instal the `.msi` version of pygame from the [official page](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) of pygame ??

Comment: Yes, it created a separate folder named PygameX. Python wouldn't  recognize that pygame was installed at all. That's why I went to the wheel.

Comment: @DaleSpencer Have you went for a tutorial on YouTube ?? I would suggest you thenewboston (https://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston)

Comment: Tried it, still no joy :(. Ended up downloading Python 2.7 then using the pygame msi for it. loaded fine. Shame though, I really like python 3.5. Thanks for your help.